# Laravel 5.2 Eloquent many to many relationship: increment post counter in tag model

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have two models, Tag and Post, and a many to many relationship between them.

When I save a post, I sync its tags, so the pivot table is updated:

```
    $post->tags()->sync($tags);
```

but I would also to increment the post counter in the tag model (field `counts` in the `tags` table).

How to do it by using Eloquent?

**EDIT**

I tried `$post->tags()->increment('counts');`, but it returns

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous
```

and the use of `const UPDATED_AT = "tablename.updated_at";` in Tag and Post models doesn't help

**SOLUTION**

I resolved with:

```
 $post_tags = $post->tags()->get();

 foreach ($post_tags as $tag) {
     $tag->increment('counts');
 }
```